# TFS 2017 - Get the Solution's name in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, build

I'd like to know how can I get the name of the solution that the XAML Build Definition is using.

For instance in the configuration of my Build Defnition I have this path to chose which solution I want to apply this Build Definition: $/test/SolutionName/SolutionName.sln

How can I get "SolutionName" for my Activity Code, using C# code.

**EDIT:** My variable, what can I put as Default yield?
[image]

The code:

```
public InArgument<string> BuildSettings { get; set; }
....
string nameSolutionAuto = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(this.BuildSettings.ProjectsToBuild[0]);
```

Comment: I will give you soon an answer, but why sticking to XAML build on 2017 which has been deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projects/solutions info is stored in ProjectsToBuild variable, so you just need to pass this variable value to your Activity (InArgument) and get the solution or project name by this code (InArgument variable:solutionPaths):

```
      foreach(string solution in solutionPaths)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(solution.Split(new char[] { '/' }).Last());
        }
```

An example to display selected solutions/projects in build definition to build log:

1. Add ForEach active (TypeArgument: String; Values: ProjectsToBuild
2. Add WriteBuildMessage active to ForEach active body (Importance: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildMessageImportance.High; Message: item
3. Queue build with this process template

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your Activity needs a property of type [BuildSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.activities.buildsettings(v=vs.120).aspx), which you set with the value of the `BuildSettings` variable.

In the Activity code, examine the content of the [ProjectsToBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.activities.buildsettings.projectstobuild(v=vs.120).aspx) property and extract the name of the solution file, e.g. `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(this.BuildSettings.ProjectsToBuild[0])`.

**EDIT**

The `BuildSettings` variable is defined globally, no need to re-define it.

The `BuildSettings` property should be

```
public InArgument<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.BuildSettings> BuildSettings { get; set; }
```

and you have to assign the `BuildSettings` **variable** to this property in the XAML Property Window.

To use it the code should be more like

```
var buildSettings = GetValue<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.BuildSettings>(this.BuildSettings);
string nameSolutionAuto = System.IO.Path.Get
FileNameWithoutExtension(buildSettings.ProjectsToBuild[0]);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, I tried to do what you explain me, but I dont understand properly, so I edit my first message to show you what I did.

Comment: Expanded answer

Comment: What kind Of value can I put for BuildSettings in the Properties in the XAML Property Window? You told me to use as value BuildSettings as value but doesn't work.